# Invalid libraryOrderEntry

Tags: android

I am trying to sync my project, I have Android studio version 3.0.1, Got error with this message :-

```
Gradle sync failed: java.lang.AssertionError: Invalid libraryOrderEntry, library: Library: name:com.android.support.test:exposed-instrumentation-api-publish-0.5; jars:JAR dirs: []; roots:[VFPContainer: [, ], VFPContainer: [], VFPContainer: [], VFPContainer: [], VFPContainer: []] of type
```

Any help would be appreiciated.

Answer (score 13):

`File > Invalidate Caches/Restart` work for me :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Every time I have to do that, I die a little inside.